# How to (if possible) set and unset session variables/ stop session cookie overwriting?

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-variables

**For background, here's my scenario:**

I'm building a self-hosted platform for a particular niche, and part of that platform is the login process, which if validated sets a session for the user. On every administration page load, the session is started and the variable `$_SESSION['key']` checked to see if it's true.

If it's false, the user is re-directed to the login page with an error telling them to login again.

The problem is this is dependant on a session cookie being set or not set, in the sense that when the session cookie expires and the session is started with `session_start()` to check `$_SESSION['key']`, therefore creating a new session cookie with default values (I use `session_set_cookie_params()` to alter the path, timeout etc) making it impossible to re-login as session cookies do not overwrite from what I can see.

In order to fix this I've thought about using something like `session_set_cookie_params(5, ..)` before `session_start()` when checking `$_SESSION['key']`, which will create a 5 second session cookie, therefore allowing a new one to be created when re-logging in, but I'm not sure whether this would work - and I'm also sure there must be a more efficient way to set/unset a session variable?

**Here's my code:**

Start session if validated login

```
if($validated){
    session_set_cookie_params(1800, "/inst", $server_name['home']); 
    session_name("_inst");
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['key'] = true;
}
```

Check if $_SESSION['key'] is still true

```
session_name("_inst");
session_start();

if(!$_SESSION['key']) {
    header('Location: ' . $server['home'] . '/login/?error=1');
}
```

Any answers or advice would be great, and please do ask if you need clarification on anything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just issue a session_start() on all pages. This'll unconditionally create a session for you, then you can check for the presence/abscence of the key:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSSION['key'])) { // never logged in, or were logged in and got logged out
   ... redirect to login ...
   exit();
}

if ($_SESSION['key'] != 'expected value') { // logged in, but no longer a valid login.
   ... redirect to login ...
   exit();
}
```

You shouldn't have to mess with the session cookie settings at all. Leave them at default and simply check for the relevant key(s). if they're not there, then the user is not logged in and should be redirected.

If their session had expired and PHP cleaned up the session file, then they've been effectively logged out, even though they have a it-was-valid-at-one-point-in-time session key, and should get redirected to login again.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but don't I still need to unset the key? I'm looking to give users maximum bouts of time (e.g. 12 hours) of login time before they need to re-login. If I don't alter the default cookie parameters, how would I be able to do this? I apologize if I didn't make this clear, I realize now I didn't really mention why I was using the `session_set_cookie_params()` function. Bottom line is, that unless I let the session drop, I need to unset/set the `$_SESSION['key']` variable every 12 hours.

Comment: you should be setting the cookie lifetime in php.ini, so it's global across all your pages, so that ALL session_start() calls would create a new cookie (if need be) with the proper expiry time. You also have to make sure that PHP's session garbage collector doesn't kick in within that 12 hour period as well (there's more .ini settings for that as well), otherwise you'll still end up with people with valid session cookies, but no matching session file because PHP cleaned it up.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that PHP had a session garbage collector. In that case, I'll simply go with the default values. Also, I completely mismatched the logic behind a session cookie, I didn't think to realize that although you can't overwrite it's parameters, you can still change the values of it's keys. I'll accept your answer, as it does actually make perfect sense, now that I've thought about it.